# Get top item in List or ScrollView

Tags: arrays, swift, listview, swiftui, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a ForEach. When an item is at the top of the scroll view, I would like to dynamically change the header at the top of the list to that item's name. I tried an onAppear, but that just sets the header title to the first item in the array.

'''

```
struct RestaurantItemList: View {
            
@State var headerTitle = "Initial Value"
            
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text(headerTitle)
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(myFoodVM.restaurantsMenu, id:\.self){item in
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ConsumableDetailView(item: item)){
                        ConsumableRowWithPicture(consumable: item)
                        .onAppear(){
                           self.headerTitle = item.name
                                   }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

'''

There doesn't seem to be any way to access the current top item in the scrollView. Does anyone have a way to access that item dynamically?

Comment: Better fit for UIKit or maybe SwiftUI Introspect. There isn’t a native SwiftUI function for this.

Comment: Use LazyVStack as a container within ScrollView then onAppear/onDisappear will work for each sub-view.

Comment: Did you tried to set a section with header = first item if the list, then foreach starting on 2nd element ? If your list is state bar somewhere it should refresh when new item added at begin

Answer (score 0):

What I **understand** from your question is you want the **name** of your **first item** of the array as the **header name**.

This is how you can **achieve** it in **.onAppear()**:

```
VStack{
     Text(headerTitle)
     ScrollView{
          ForEach(myFoodVM.restaurantsMenu, id:\.self){item in
              HStack{
                 NavigationLink(destination: ConsumableDetailView(item: item)){
                      ConsumableRowWithPicture(consumable: item)
         
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }.onAppear{
            headerTitle = myFoodVM.restaurantsMenu.first.name
    }
```

Comment: I want the header to change as I scroll. The name it displays should be whichever items is DISPLAYED at the top of the list. Not the first item in that lists array.